# How come the 1st reducer is taking the value of the 2nd reducer when program terminates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I have 2 reducers: `winnerReducer` and `gameLockedReducer`.  The last 2 lines in the `console` shows that `gameLockedReducer` took the value (`X wins!`) from `winnerReducer`.  It's working fine, the way it's intended to up until the aforementioned last 2 lines.

I mean, they're both clearly in two different initial states, how's it even possible that this is happening?

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Here's the output in the `console`:

```
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> undefined
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> undefined
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> undefined
Board.js:31 this.gameState.totalMoves ==> 1
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> true
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> false
Board.js:31 this.gameState.totalMoves ==> 2
Board.js:31 this.gameState.totalMoves ==> 3
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> true
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> false
Board.js:31 this.gameState.totalMoves ==> 4
Board.js:31 this.gameState.totalMoves ==> 5
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> true
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> false
Board.js:31 this.gameState.totalMoves ==> 6
Board.js:78 6
Board.js:31 this.gameState.totalMoves ==> 7
winnerReducer.js:10 [winnerReducer] => X wins!
gameLockedReducer.js:8 [gameLockedReducer] ==> X wins!
```

Here's

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Board.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionTypes from '../../store/actions/actions';

class Board extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.gameState = {
            turn: 'X',
            gameLocked: false,
            gameEnded: false,
            board: Array(9).fill(''),
            totalMoves: 0
        }
    }

    clicked(box) {
        if(this.gameState.gameEnded || this.props.gameLockedValue) {
            return;
        }

        if(this.gameState.board[box.dataset.square] === '') {
            this.gameState.board[box.dataset.square] = this.gameState.turn;
            box.innerText = this.gameState.turn;

            this.gameState.turn = this.gameState.turn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
            this.gameState.totalMoves++;
        }

        console.log("this.gameState.totalMoves ==> " + this.gameState.totalMoves);

        var result = this.checkWinner();

        switch(result) {
            case 'X':
                this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
                this.props.winnerValueRedux("X wins!");
                break;
            case 'O':
                this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
                this.props.winnerValueRedux("O wins!");
                break;
            case 'draw':
                this.gameState.gameEnded = true;
                this.props.winnerValueRedux("Match is a draw");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // console.log("result ==> " + result);

        if(this.gameState.turn === 'O' && !this.gameState.gameEnded) {
            this.props.gameLockedValueRedux(true);
            // this.gameState.gameLocked = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                do {
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
                } while(this.gameState.board[random] !== '');
                this.props.gameLockedValueRedux(false);
                // console.log("reached here");
                this.clicked(document.querySelectorAll('.square')[random]);
            }, 3000)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="game">
                <div id="state">{this.props.winnerValue} {this.props.gameLockedValue}</div>

                <div id="head">
                    Tic Tac Toe
                </div>

                <div id="board" onClick={(e) => this.clicked(e.target)}>
                    <div className="square" data-square="0"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="1"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="2"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="3"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="4"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="5"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="6"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="7"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="8"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        winnerValue: state.winnerValue.winnerValue,
        gameLockedValue: state.gameLockedValue.gameLockedValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        winnerValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.WINNER_VALUE, value}),
        gameLockedValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.GAME_LOCKED_VALUE, value})
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Board);
```

Here's `winnerReducer`:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    winnerValue: ""
};

const winnerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.WINNER_VALUE:
            console.log("[winnerReducer] => " + action.value);
            return{
                ...state,
                winnerValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default winnerReducer;
```

Here's `gameLockedReducer`:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    gameLockedValue: false
};

const gameLockedReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log("[gameLockedReducer] ==> " + action.value);
    switch(action) {

        case actionTypes.GAME_LOCKED_VALUE:

            return {
                ...state,
                gameLockedValue: true
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default gameLockedReducer;
```

Comment: can you please share the reducer code as well ?

Comment: @PranayTripathi posted, check my original post

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with console.log in the gameLockedReducer. By default, all the actions are passed to the reducer. Depending upon the actionType, you modify the state. In the case of gameLockedReducer, the console log get printed as it also receives the dispatch but it doesn't actually change the state as there is none of the switch case is satisfied in the reducer. If you put the same console log in the case actionTypes.GAME_LOCKED_VALUE, you should get proper logging behaviour as you expect. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I put the console.log inside the case, then `[gameLockedReducer]` doesn't even appear in the console.

Comment: which is correct as you are only passing winnerValueRedux action when there is a winner. so the action will processed by winnerReducer as the action matches there. as the actionType doesn't satisfy the switch case in gameLockedReducer, hence there is no logging.

Comment: ah I see what you're saying.  So how do I fix it so that it does logged correctly?

Comment: I believe you can pass a separate action to the [gameLockedReducer] where you want the state in [gameLockedReducer] to be modified as per that actionType and you can do logging in the same case as well.

Comment: But I'm passing a separate action to the [gameLockedReducer]  already aren't I?  Both parameters for both of the reducer for `case` is different.  Namely, `case actionTypes.WINNER_VALUE:` and `case actionTypes.GAME_LOCKED_VALUE:`.

Comment: as your variable gameState.gameEnded get true when a winner is decided, your gameLockedAction is never called as per the conditon `if(this.gameState.turn === 'O' && !this.gameState.gameEnded)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181447/discussion-between-sp92-and-pranay-tripathi).